# Filemaker 18 Curl Not Post file contents

Tags: curl, filemaker

Filemaker 18 Curl Not Post file contents:

I'm trying to send a mixed content request to my webserver and when specify a file to attach the file contents are not being sent. (There is something that exists on the payload)

I have made sure that the server is receiving the proper variables (which it is) and have also tried to copy and paste the same options via a bash shell.

"-X POST " &

"--header Content-Type:multipart/form-data " &

" -form \"fileName=" & "test.jpeg"  & "\""&

" -F \"file=@$file;type=image/jpeg;\" "

$file is my filepath the the image.

This works correctly via command line: curl -X POST -F "fileName=5433_PI.jpg" -F "file=@/Users/jasonmadden/Downloads/Rewrite.png" http://127.0.0.1:5000/generate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $file is my filepath the the image.

AFAIK, the variable needs to contain actual image data, not a path to an external file.

Comment: Michael is correct, you don't have access to the file system from Insert from URL, so the file needs to be in a FileMaker container, which the variable is then set to contain.

Comment: You can use Insert File to insert the file directly into the variable, without an intermediate container field.

Comment: TYVM.  The responses from  @michael.hor257k helped me solve my problem.

The insert file command was the key I needed.